# JavaScript React Front-End: Opening one collapse button, all collapse buttons open instead of just the one

Tags: html, reactjs, render, react-bootstrap

I am trying to setup a toggle button in react JSX. When I click the **Order Details Toggle** button I want the toggle to only open for the selected order.

Right now, I am able to do that.  But the other content Cards (react bootstrap Card) open up as well.  The other cards' order details are not shown which is good but their boxes get weirdly elongated.

Please see below:

[image]

In my example above, only the Card associated with order id 2 should open.  The other three cards should retain their original size.

Below is my React code on the front-end:

```
import React from 'react'
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
import {toDollars, getOrders} from '../store/allOrders' // sortOrders
import {updateOrderThunk, fetchSingleOrder} from '../store/singleOrder'
// Status Filter import BeerFilter from './BeerFilter'
import Card from 'react-bootstrap/Card'
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button'
import {UncontrolledCollapse, CardBody} from 'reactstrap'

export class AllOrders extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      showForm: false,
      stat: ''
    }
    this.clickHandlerOne = this.clickHandlerOne.bind(this)
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this)
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    try {
      this.props.fetchInitialOrders()
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error)
    }
  }

  clickHandlerOne() {
    let hidden = this.state.showForm
    this.setState({
      showForm: !hidden
    })
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    //console.log('event.target', event.target)
    this.setState({
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value
    })
  }

  async handleSubmit(orderId) {
    event.preventDefault()

    const updatedOrder = {
      id: orderId,
      status: this.state.stat
    }

    // console.log('UPDATE ORDER', updatedOrder)

    await this.props.updateOrderThunk(updatedOrder)
    this.props.fetchInitialOrders()
  }

  render() {
    const orders = this.props.orders
    // console.log('PROPS', this.props)
    console.log('ORDERS', this.props.orders)

    // const beers = orders.beers || []

    return (
      <div>
        {/* <div className="options">
          <select onChange={this.handleChange}>
            <option value="">Sort By...</option>
            <option value="priceHighToLow">Price (high to low)</option>
            <option value="priceLowToHigh">Price (low to high)</option>
            <option value="name">Name</option>
          </select>

          <BeerFilter />
    </div> */}

        <div className="flex-cards">
          {orders.map(order => (
            <Card style={{width: '18rem'}} key={order.id}>
              <Card.Body>
                <Card.Title>Order Id: {order.id}</Card.Title>
                <Card.Text>
                  <div>
                    <ul>
                      <li>
                        <div className="highlight">
                          <img src={order.user.imageUrl} />
                        </div>
                        <div className="details">
                          <p>User: {order.user.username}</p>
                          <p>Order Status: {order.status}</p>
                          <p>
                            Order Date:{' '}
                            {new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-GB', {
                              month: 'short',
                              day: '2-digit',
                              year: 'numeric'
                            }).format(new Date(order.createdAt))}
                          </p>
                          <div>
                            {' '}
                            Total Quantity:
                            {order.beers.reduce(function(totalQuantity, beer) {
                              return (
                                beer['beer-orders'].quantity + totalQuantity
                              )
                            }, 0)}
                          </div>
                          {/* */}
                          <div>
                            {' '}
                            Total Price:
                            {toDollars(
                              order.beers.reduce(function(totalPrice, beer) {
                                return (
                                  beer.price * beer['beer-orders'].quantity +
                                  totalPrice
                                )
                              }, 0)
                            )}
                          </div>
                          {/* */}
                          <Button
                            id={`status${order.id}`}
                            onClick={() => {
                              this.clickHandlerOne()
                            }}
                            variant="outline-primary"
                          >
                            Update Status Toggle
                          </Button>
                          <UncontrolledCollapse toggler={`#status${order.id}`}>
                            <form onSubmit={() => this.handleSubmit(order.id)}>
                              <div>
                                <span>
                                  <select
                                    name="stat"
                                    value={
                                      typeof order.status === 'string'
                                        ? this.state.stat
                                        : order.status
                                    }
                                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                                  >
                                    <option value="">
                                      select order status
                                    </option>
                                    <option value="open">open</option>
                                    <option value="processing">
                                      processing
                                    </option>
                                    <option value="cancelled">cancelled</option>
                                  </select>
                                </span>

                                <div>
                                  {/* */}
                                  <button type="submit">Edit</button>
                                </div>
                              </div>

                              {/* delete thunk
                                <span>
                                  <p>
                                    <button type="button">Delete</button>
                                  </p>
                                </span>
                                */}
                            </form>
                          </UncontrolledCollapse>
                          <div> -----------------------------------------</div>
                          <Button
                            variant="info"
                            id={`order${order.id}`}
                            style={{marginBottom: '1rem'}}
                          >
                            Order Details Toggle
                          </Button>
                          <UncontrolledCollapse toggler={`#order${order.id}`}>
                            <Card>
                              <CardBody>
                                <span>
                                  <div>
                                    {order.beers.length === 0
                                      ? `${order.user.username} has no orders!`
                                      : order.beers.map(beer => (
                                          <div key={beer.id}>
                                            <p> Beer Name: {beer.name} </p>
                                            <img src={beer.imageUrl} />
                                            <p>
                                              {' '}
                                              Beer Description:{' '}
                                              {beer.description}{' '}
                                            </p>
                                            <p> Beer IBU: {beer.ibu} </p>
                                            <p>
                                              {' '}
                                              Beer Price:{' '}
                                              {toDollars(beer.price)}{' '}
                                            </p>

                                            <div>
                                              {' '}
                                              --------------------------------
                                            </div>
                                          </div>
                                        ))}
                                  </div>
                                </span>
                              </CardBody>
                            </Card>
                          </UncontrolledCollapse>
                        </div>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                </Card.Text>
              </Card.Body>
            </Card>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    orders: state.allOrders
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    loadSingleOrder: id => dispatch(fetchSingleOrder(id)),
    updateOrderThunk: updatedOrder => dispatch(updateOrderThunk(updatedOrder)),
    //getSortedBeers: (sortBy, beers) => dispatch(sortBeers(sortBy, beers)),
    fetchInitialOrders: () => dispatch(getOrders())
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(AllOrders)
```

How can I fix my code so I can get it to render the toggling appropriately?

Comment: add a key when looping

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is here:

```
<Button
  variant="primary"
  id="toggler"
  style={{marginBottom: '1rem'}}
>
  Order Details Toggle
</Button>
<UncontrolledCollapse toggler="#toggler">
```

ID attribute must be unique (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id)

A fix:

```
<Button
  variant="primary"
  id={order.id}
  style={{marginBottom: '1rem'}}
>
  Order Details Toggle
</Button>
<UncontrolledCollapse toggler={`#${order.id}`}>
```

Comment: thank you for the suggestion.  I tried your code above and got the following error: utils.js:183 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelectorAll' on 'Document': '#1' is not a valid selector.

Comment: @CoolGuy what do you mean?

Comment: @PineNuts0 In this reply, he uses order.id as id property. But id should be started with _ or english letter as mentioned here(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id).  You may try  this: ```<Button
  variant="primary"
  id={`order${order.id}`}
  style={{marginBottom: '1rem'}}
>
  Order Details Toggle
</Button>
<UncontrolledCollapse toggler={`#order${order.id}`}>```